# Change free text sorting - OTRS ITSM

Tags: html, perl, change-management, otrs

Hi I want to show free text fields in Change overview , I edited the AgentITSMChangeOverviewSmall.dtl file and added code for change free text. Change free text field is visible in Change Overview but I am enable to sort as we can do with other attributes.

Here is my code:

```
    <th class="ChangeFreeText1 $QData{"CSS"}">
    <a href="$Env{"Baselink"}Action=$Env{"Action"};$Data{"LinkSort"};SortBy=ChangeFreeText1;
     OrderBy=$LQData{"OrderBy"}">$Text{"ChangeFreeText1"}</a>
    </th>   

   <td>
   <div>$Text{"$Data{"ChangeFreeText1"}"}</div>
   </td>
```

Can someone tell me whats missing in my code.

Answer (score 0):

The backend Kernel::System::ITSMChange ChangeSearch() does not support ordering by FreeText fields, unfortunately, so you should add that as well.

Comment: Can you please elaborate little more as Free text fields are stored in different table than change_item table.  @michielb